# batch image compression on ubuntu (lossy)

Tags: ubuntu, batch-processing, image-compression

Its strange but I cannot find a good **image compression** tool (ala IrfanView on windows) on **ubuntu** to recompress images in order to save disk space (yes! I care about it :)).

I am looking for web standard image details.

Earlier, I had used digikam but it doesnt support recompression nowadays (tools->recompress doesnt exist)

Gimp : no batch mode of recompression

jpegoptim, adept : few details regarding parameters to specify for optimal use.

trimage : hangs on my system (desktop froze for compressing 600+ images).

Any other ?

Comment: Ubunto doesn't run batch files which are Windows files. Please remove the tag.

Comment: @Serenity, you got me wrong. I didnt mention execing windows batch files in ubuntu. but recompressing list of image files.

Comment: hard to see why the question is downmodded. curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converseen : available from Software Center

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! @user3726045

Answer (score 0):

try mogrify:

```
mogrify -resize 50% rose.jpg

mogrify -format jpg *.png
```

more details from here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php

Comment: my use case is jpg-> jpg lossy recompression.
eg is IrfanView on windows. It keeps the pic resolution but recompresses the jpgs.